# Pasting code in a terminal Vim (:set paste vs <c-r>* vs ..)

Tags: linux, vim, paste

There seem to be several ways to paste code into terminal Vim w/o destroying indentation or turning it into comments:

- `:set paste` + ordinary OS paste
- Pasting using the registers `*` and `+`, e.g. `<c-o>"+p`
- `:set mouse=a` + pasting with mouse
- ?

I wonder which is a better practice / more universal approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasting from `normal` doesn't indent.  I think the simplest, most portable way is `<c-o>"+p`.  Since it avoids `pastetoggle`, it would also work with NeoVim.

Possible no-indent/indent maps...

```
inoremap <silent> <f3> <c-o>"+p
inoremap <silent> <f4> <c-r>+
```

There is one small problem with the above though.  It leaves the cursor at the beginning instead of the end of the pasted text for pasting without indent.

To leave the cursor in the same place...

```
inoremap <silent> <f3> <c-o>:set paste<cr><c-r>+<c-o>:set nopaste<cr>
inoremap <silent> <f4> <c-o>:set nopaste<cr><c-r>+
```

Comment: `It leaves the cursor at the beginning instead of the end of the pasted text` — I'm not having this problem actually.

Comment: @eugeney I tried Vim and NeoVim and got the same with both.  I think another way to normalize might be jumping to the last insert spot.though `<c-o>g'[`.  That leaves the cursor at the beginning instead of the end.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it depends on OS and features Vim is built with, but in my case registers `*` and `+` are empty in terminal Vim. They are not empty in gVim, but gVim handles pasting correctly anyway, without setting `'paste'`. So if I want to paste something into terminal Vim, I need to `set paste`.

Answer (score 0):

You may find these two settings useful for pasting stuff into terminal Vim:

```
set clipboard^=unnamed
set mouse=a
```

The first setting [enables the use of the system clipboard](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/3ae4qf/psa_set_clipboardunnamed/) (the `"*` register) for yanking and pasting from/to Vim, and the second one makes pasting with mouse work correctly.

It may still be useful to have a mapping for `pastetoggle`, e.g. when editing files over SSH.